# Is there an RPG.SE button / graphic / banner?

Tags: support, site-promotion

I have a website (well, a few) and I would like to link to RPG.SE. Rather than use a text link, I'd like to use an image as they get better click-throughs. Is there an image I can use to link the to site?

I *could* make my own using the banner as the starting point but I doubt that would look as professional as if it was done by the original artist. A range of shapes and sizes would be great but most blogs and sites use a 120px by 120px.

I did hunt and search around the main site and meta for one but couldn't find any.

Comment: I'll try to get you an answer on this soon...

Comment: Victory is yours?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you go!

[image: RPG Stack Exchange 120px banner]

Comment: that is epic. TYVM

Comment: My pleasure. Let me know if you guys need banner in other sizes.

Comment: Brilliant Jin, that is EXACTLY what I was after. ;-)