# Off-site Community Promotion Ads

Tags: discussion, advertising

As far as I know, we don't have any RPG.SE ads to submit to the Community Promo metas on *other* Stacks. (We have [this ad made by Jin for general web promo](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1635/is-there-an-rpg-se-button-graphic-banner/post1636#1636), but it's the wrong size and shape for Community Promo metas.) Going through [our own old Community Promo metas](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1497/community-promotion-ads-2012), I noticed that other Stacks have been more organised and proactive about this kind thing than we have — we've mostly been the target of cross-promotion, not the initiators.

So this is where we change that (or not, if the votes say 'meh'). Submit your RPG.SE ad designs below so we can discuss, collaborate, and submit the best of them to our sibling Stacks!

## A note on common design types

Judging by other Stacks' promo ads, there are two common approaches to designing ads: general-use and site-customised. General-use ads represent their Stack clearly no matter which other Stack they appear on, while customised ads highlight the crossover that might appeal to a user of the other Stack and entice them to click through to the advertised Stack.

Obviously general gives more reuse of the initial effort, but my impression is that custom is better at getting clicks (and probably votes in their metas). Either would be an improvement over our current none though, and both are useful in different ways, so take this as food for thought when thinking of and voting on designs, rather than guidance on what we "should" make.

Comment: As someone who might make these ads, I'd like suggestions about *which* sites it'd be good to customise for.

Comment: @BESW That'd be great! Any that have ever posted well-voted ads with us are a good self-selected list. That includes SF&F, Anime, and Worldbuilding. We might also consider Movies&TV ("play your own show!"), History (marginal, so probably only a good custom "don't just research it, make your own" one), and Arqade (ditto).

Comment: I'd highly reccomend http://writers.stackexchange.com/ and http://english.stackexchange.com/ as well.  Also, an oddly high number of computer geeks are also RPG geeks so we may want to try Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've compiled a reference list of sites as a CW along with some investigation notes.

Answer (score 5):

## An incomplete list of SEs with some degree of overlap in audience

Entries link directly to the SE's [community-ads] tag on meta.

Bear in mind every SE site can also accept Community Ads at double their normal size (600×500 px) for improved display on Retina displays and similar, as well as the standard 300×250. That includes our site! ([See this meta for confirmation.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247063/152515))

- [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

  Have advertised with us, making acceptance of a reciprocal ad more likely.
- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

  Ads that aren't "game-relevant" in at least some passing way do poorly in the voting there, historically. (Compare: [A](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8059/4163) vs [B](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8066/4163).) A generic "RPG.SE is great!" ad will probably not make the cut.
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)
- <strike>[Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)</strike>

  **Stack Overflow will not accept a CA about RPG.SE.** CAs on SO are strictly limited to "[advertisement[s] soliciting the participation and contribution of programmers writing actual source code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015)" for open source projects. We can cross SO off our list of potential advertising sites. This entry is here for informational purposes, especially to explain why well-meaning suggestions that we advertise there won't be considered.
- [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

  Have advertised with us, and have indicated interest in a reciprocal ad. One is being [workshopped](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6036/23970) right now.
- [Movies & TV](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

### Beta sites

The following sites of interest have not yet had Community Ads activated (subject to change):

- [Anime & Manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)
- [History](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)
- [Writers](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)
- [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads)

Comment: It could be dangerous to advertise on Arqade. We already get a bunch of questions that belong there.

Comment: @Miniman If people *already are there*, presumably they know about Arqade and don’t need to be told about it. But it is a good idea, perhaps, to emphasize the difference *in* the ad. "For when you want to ditch the computer," or something.

Comment: @KRyan Good point. From that point of view, having an Arqade ad (that also emphasizes the difference) here could be helpful too.